# What does "muddy elbow of the Charles River" mean? Is it some sort of a joke?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I was watching Conan's Dartmouth commencement speech and he said "But fate dealt a heavy blow. With no money, I was forced to enroll in a small, local commuter school, a pulsating sore on a muddy elbow of the Charles River."

I believe this expression is supposed to be funny, but I don't understand and can't find any related info either.. Someone please help me

Comment: The metaphor 'elbow' is often used for 'a bend in a river'; here it is extended by twinning with the metaphorical use of 'sore' (an unwelcome nuisance or worse: [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sore) has [noun ... 2]  'a source of pain or vexation'). An unusual but quite acceptable twinning, so a pun.

Comment: Funny, it is not, but a complex image intended to impart to the reader the impression of meanness that the narrator is infused with, it certainly is. However, the present site has for purpose to discuss grammar, the semantic of words and terms, etymology, morphology, regional particularities of the language, pronunciation and its regional particularities, but not much more. Your question has to be asked on another site (maybe Literature).

Comment: @LPH Since it's a twinned metaphor, and both are non-creative (non-D-I-Y) (both metaphorical usages can be found in dictionaries), I'd say this is reasonably scoped for ELU. But no research is shown (both metaphorical usages can be found in dictionaries).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: if you don't realize that the whole expression refers to Harvard University, you're not going to get the main reason that it's funny.

Comment: The setup is Dickensian. Some in the audience may have recognized where he was going by "commuter school," but likely even "a pulsating sore" flowed by smoothly for most, only turning to waves of laughter when he reached "elbow on the Charles River."

Comment: From _The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language_, fifth edition (2010): **elbow** _n._ ... **3.** ... **b.** A sharp bend in a river or road." The relevant definition in  _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003) is less explicit: "**elbow** _n_ ... **2 :** something (as macaroni or an angular pipe fitting) resembling an elbow." Even though MW doesn't include a specific definition of _elbow_ related to a bend in a river, this question seems to me to be borderline general reference.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is answerable by consulting a general-reference dictionary.

Comment: @SvenYargs: A general-reference dictionary won't answer the OP's real question — why did everybody laugh when Conan O'Brien said this? (In their words, "is it some sort of a joke?")

Answer (score 6):

This is a reference to Harvard University. It is indeed on a bend of the Charles River, and Conan O'Brien went to college there. It's one of Dartmouth's chief rivals, and I am sure that the audience was greatly amused by Conan calling it "a small, local commuter school, a pulsating sore ..."

The reason the Charles is called "muddy" is that, besides it being a somewhat disparaging term, Bostonians themselves call it "muddy". See the Standell's song [Dirty Water](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_C5DAeO-I7Y).

For the actual English content of this question: An "elbow" of a river here refers to a bend in it.  One of the definitions Lexico has for *elbow* is

> A thing resembling an elbow, in particular a piece of piping bent through an angle.

And Conan extends the metaphor by referring to Harvard as "a pulsating sore on a muddy elbow of ..."